# Concurrent edit with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I've implemented a lock entity method for concurrent entity editing (user can't start editing before locking it). Information about locked entities is stored in table.

Here is the code that implements locking.

```
public virtual ObjectLockInfo Lock(int id)
{
        using (var context = DataContextFactory.GetContext())
        {                
             var i =
                context.ObjectLock.Any(
                    c =>
                        c.ObjectID == id && (c.ObjectType == (int) _lockObjectType) &&
                        c.LockExpireDate > DateTime.Now);

            if (i)
                return new ObjectLockInfo
                {
                    ErrorMessage = "Object is locked",
                    IsLocked = false
                };

            var lockLock = new ObjectLock
            {
                LockExpireDate = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(20),
                LockObjectDate = DateTime.Now,
                ObjectID = id,
                ObjectType = (int) _lockObjectType,
                UserID = _currentUserID
            };

            context.ObjectLock.Add(lockLock);
            context.SaveChanges();
            return new ObjectLockInfo
            {
                Id = lockLock.ID,
                IsLocked = true,
                LockDate = lockLock.LockObjectDate,
                LockExpireDate = lockLock.LockExpireDate
            };
        }

    }
```

This code has a problem: if we get another lock request before `context.SaveChanges()` is executed (and it passes `Any` condition), we will get two locks on the table.

How to avoid it (without using `INSTEAD OF INSERT` trigger)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a transaction with [Serializable isolation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms709374(v=vs.85).aspx), this will prevent "phantom rows" which is what you are concerned about.

```
public virtual ObjectLockInfo Lock(int id)
{
    using (var context = DataContextFactory.GetContext())
    using (var dbContextTransaction = context.Database.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.Serializable)) 
    {                
         var i =
            context.ObjectLock.Any(
                c =>
                    c.ObjectID == id && (c.ObjectType == (int) _lockObjectType) &&
                    c.LockExpireDate > DateTime.Now);

        if (i)
            return new ObjectLockInfo
            {
                ErrorMessage = "Object is locked",
                IsLocked = false
            };

        var lockLock = new ObjectLock
        {
            LockExpireDate = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(20),
            LockObjectDate = DateTime.Now,
            ObjectID = id,
            ObjectType = (int) _lockObjectType,
            UserID = _currentUserID
        };

        context.ObjectLock.Add(lockLock);
        context.SaveChanges();

        dbContextTransaction.Commit();

        return new ObjectLockInfo
        {
            Id = lockLock.ID,
            IsLocked = true,
            LockDate = lockLock.LockObjectDate,
            LockExpireDate = lockLock.LockExpireDate
        };
    }

}
```

Now once the `Any` has been performed no other writer will be able to write to the table (or reader read from it if their own transaction is `Read Commited` or higher) until you commit your changes.